# AWS EC2: ssh through port 443 although apache is installed on instance

Tags: tcp, ssh, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ip

I want to be able to ssh into my instances from work but I am behing a corporate firewall and port 22 is closed. Yesterday I changed the ssh config file and replaced port 22 with port 80 but then everything broke down (couldn't ssh into the instance anymore) because apache is installed and already uses port 80.
What about port 443? I  have no use for https on this instance and I could  use it to connect with ssh, but will it trigger the same problem?

Another question: will it interfer with curl, which I use to retrieve webpages all the time?

P.s: for those interested, here is how I solved my problem from yesterday

1. Stopped the instance, dettached the 
   EBS volume
2. Attached and mounted the volume (NOT as root drive) to another instance
3. Connected to the other instance and restablished the config file with port 22 using vi editor
4. Dettached the volume, reattached it as root drive on the old instance, rebooted: Voila

Comment: Information about how you solved your problem from yesterday belongs on the same page as your question from yesterday, not here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If Apache does not use port 443, then no, it will not be a problem.

If Apache uses port 443, then yes, it will be a problem. But you can reconfigure Apache to not use port 443.

Assuming your instance is running Linux/BSD, run `netstat -ltn` to find out which tcp ports are being listened on.

It will not interfere with curl: curl does not listen; it is a client not a server.